# Is there a way to modify kubernetes object's metadata?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources

I'm trying to modify a k8s object's metadata?

When I do `kubectl edit ....` on that object and make changes and save it, it's saying `edited`.

But when I do `kubectl describe` on that object, it's still showing old values in metadata.

Comment: In typical use I'd edit the YAML file you've checked in to source control, and `kubectl apply` that.  Some things you should be able to change (`labels:`), but others define the object itself (`name:`) and can't be updated.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the object that's already created without actually modifying the yaml file and applying.

Comment: The problem with `kubectl edit` is that the next time you do a normal deployment, the `helm upgrade` or `kubectl apply` will overwrite your manual changes, and if your pod is acting funny, "we made some changes by hand in the cluster" isn't really a good description.

Comment: What are you actually trying to change that's not getting reflected?  Can you provide a [mcve]?